# Why mongodb me back [] when it does not find anything?

Tags: mongodb

I'm making a query(MongoDB), and there isn't nothing in the bbdd, that's Ok, but the response have this [ ], why?

```
Gato.find(function(err, gatos) { 
    if(err) res.send(500, err.message);
    res.status(200).jsonp(gatos); 
});
```

How do I know if it's empty?,I dont want to validate if it's empty with []

I dont want

```
if (arrayBack != [])
```

Any idea?
THX!

Comment: But what did you expect? MongoDB found 0 documents, so it returned you an array with 0 documents. You could validate that response isn't empty by checking its `length`, e.g. `docs.length > 0`.

Comment: of course... if (!arrayBack.length)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have provided a valid query. The result is an empty set (an empty array). You can use `arrayBack.length == 0` to test whether it has any data.